# Should every API call dispatch an action when using NgRx?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In every example I see with NgRx, they seem to dispatch an action for every HTTP call to the backend. However, in my app, most API calls simply fetch data that other screens don't care about. Other bits of data though are shared across different screens, and therefore I am using NgRx. Is there anything wrong with not dispatching an action for every HTTP call?

Thanks.

Comment: No - there is nothing wrong with that. If you have transient data that is only used inside the life-cycle of a single component and doesn't have to persist or be shared, you can simply do a service call directly inside that component. Another option though is to use theNGRX component store for this kind of data: https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store

Comment: That's not wrong. If you don't need complex state management, ngrx then is reduntant. Angular services are mostly easy and very useful on handling state management & making api calls.